# Why doesn't empty string == null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I understand that both empty string and null are falsy according to the ECMAScript. If both are falsy then why doesn't the following evaluate to true?

```
    var emptyString = '';
    if (emptyString == null) {
        console.log('emptyString == null');
    }
    else {
        console.log('emptyString does not == null'); // but why?
    }
```

Comment: Because an empty string is not the same as *no string*.

Comment: Because you're not comparing each to false(y), you're comparing an empty string to a null value.

Comment: It's easier to understand in other languages that let you manipulate pointers directly (e.g. C). An empty string has a value, and that value is a single null character. `null` means a variable that holds no value.

Comment: Apples and oranges are both fruit, but `apples == oranges` would also evaluate false.

Comment: You can read more on the topic Literals - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8

Comment: This question isn't that farfetched.  The equality operator in JavaScript performs type coercion and is somewhat inconsistent.  For example, `'' == []` is true, but `''` is a falsey value and `[]` is a truthy value.  Also `null == undefined` is true, so there is at least one other case where `null` "equals" another falsey value.

Comment: The falsy definition is what trips me up because I understood that the `==` did not check types and only checks values (or representation). Since `'1' == 1` evaluates to true I expected similar results here.

Comment: Also just to prove why I am confused by all of this; try `0 == ''` and you will see that it in fact evaluates to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more commonly used abstract comparison (e.g. ==) converts the operands to the same Type before making the comparison.

Here, null is a falsy value, but null is not == false

The falsy values null and undefined are not equivalent to anything except themselves:

```
(null == false); // false
(null == null); // true
(undefined == undefined); // true
(undefined == null); // true
```

since the other operand is null( which is also a type in javascript ), the abstract comparison of empty string(falsy value) and null doesn't give a truthy value.

I think this will help you.

[Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

and this too

[Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: I suppose this is starting to make sense now. In practice you wouldn't want anything to `==` or `=== null` since `null` should be used to check against other values and types. Which is exactly why they have a truthy/falsy evaluations for other values and types. That provides a way for something like `if (emptyString)` which can be used to substitute the check for null if you do not know whether or not the value you will be receiving is an empty string or null.

Answer (score 5):

> both empty string and null are falsy

Yes, but that doesn't mean all falsy values would be equal to each other. `NaN` and `0` are both falsy as well, but they're definitely not equal. The reverse doesn't hold either, `"0" == 0` but `"0"` ain't falsy.

The sloppy equivalence of values is defined by the [Abstract Equality Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) and its type coercions, and `null` simply isn't `==` to anything but `undefined`.